# Error terraform init, plan , apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm facing the below error when terraform init, plan or apply

```
Failed to load backend: 
Error configuring the backend "s3": RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://sts.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup sts.amazonaws.com on 127.0.1.1:53: server misbehaving

Please update the configuration in your Terraform files to fix this error.
If you'd like to update the configuration interactively without storing
the values in your configuration, run "terraform init".
```

Any clues ?

Comment: Looks like it's failing to resolve the service. What's the output of `dig sts.amazonaws.com`? That DNS server looks like a local DNSMasq, are you doing anything special there or is it just a stock caching server?

Comment: Had a similar issue 'Error configuring the backend "s3": RequestError: send request failed' and it added up been a problem with the ssl on my Mac (libressl), restart did the trick

Comment: This gave a workaround for me: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5419#issuecomment-522051353

Answer (score 2):

If you are on MacOS and have LittleSnitch installed, then terraform gets blocked by little snitch due to it's invalid signature. Just go and delete the corresponding rule or modify it in LittleSnitch.

Comment: OMG I wasted sooo much time here lol! I use LuLu and BlockBlock by Objective-See, which does similar traffic filtering and blocking to LittleSnitch. They normally prompt to allow unclassified network access, but not in this case for the AWS look-ups. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a connectivity issue between your machine and s3. This might be happening due to the unstable internet for that time period.

It should fix automatically once you are able to connect with the s3.