# terraform plan stuck at GetCallerIdentity action on Mac Apple M1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a s3 bucket using terraform.

My main.tf file:

```
  terraform {
      required_providers {
              aws = {
                     source = "hashicorp/aws"
                     version = "= 3.74.1"
              }
      }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "random_id" "my-random-id" {
  byte_length = 2
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-test-bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.s3_bucket_name}-${random_id.my-random-id.dec}"
  acl = "private"
  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "test-terraform"
  }
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {}
```

On running `terraform init && terraform plan`, execution gets stuck at `GetCallerIndentity` action. This is what I see in the logs:

```
Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15
-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2022-10-28T20:19:20.497+0530
2022-10-28T20:19:50.498+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-aws_v3.74.1_x5: 2022/10/28 20:19:50 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Send Request sts/GetCallerIdentity failed, attempt 1/25, error RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://sts.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: i/o timeout: timestamp=2022-10-28T20:19:50.498+0530
2022-10-28T20:19:50.619+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-aws_v3.74.1_x5: 2022/10/28 20:19:50 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Retrying Request sts/GetCallerIdentity, attempt 2: timestamp=2022-10-28T20:19:50.619+0530
2022-10-28T20:19:50.619+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-aws_v3.74.1_x5: 2022/10/28 20:19:50 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request sts/GetCallerIdentity Details:
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: sts.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.3.3 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/3.74.1 (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws) aws-sdk-go/1.42.38 (go1.16; darwin; arm64)
Content-Length: 43
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<aws_access_key>/20221028/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=f99701b1369111709baf25e7bb8813918ff7e08b0503a55cdb8ef26d7924bd9d
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-Amz-Date: 20221028T144950Z
X-Amz-Security-Token: <aws_security_token>
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

On running `aws s3 ls` using aws cli, it fetches me correct list of buckets.

I am new to Terraform and would appreciate some help in fixing this. I have tried with multiple versions of `aws providers` in config but to no use.

Comment: Can you remove the `.terraform` directory and run `terraform init` right after that?

Comment: Did you check these threads: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10779 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922631/error-terraform-init-plan-apply ?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, tried cleaning and running init multiple times, but the issue persists. I am not in a VPN either

Comment: Are using a specific STS endpoint, i.e., not the default one? Is there something in the AWS configuration files that would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem on my Windows machine, which had antivirus software installed.

My attempts to resolve the issue included various strategies such as changing my Wi-Fi network, turning off my antivirus software, and explicitly including the access key within the Terraform configuration file, all of which were unsuccessful.

The breakthrough came when I used a different computer, which did not have antivirus software installed, connected to the same Wi-Fi network. On this system, I generated a new access key, configured it using `aws-configure`, and then successfully executed `terraform init` and `plan`. This led me to conclude that the original access key might have been the issue.

Following this discovery, I generated a new access key for my Windows machine, adhered to the same setup process (retaining the antivirus enabled and using the same Wi-Fi connection). This time, the operations were successful.

Below is the Terraform configuration snippet I utilized:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-0e731c8a588258d0d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

The steps I followed were:

1. Run `aws configure` to set up the access keys.
2. Execute `terraform init` to initialize the Terraform working directory.
3. Use `terraform plan` to create an execution plan.
4. Apply the plan using `terraform apply`.
5. Destroy the resources with `terraform destroy` once done.

This approach resolved my issue, suggesting that the key factor might have been the access key rather than network or antivirus configurations in my case.